# Why isn't a script executed during provisioning an Ubuntu VM using Vagrant shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, vagrant, provisioning

I'm trying to install [dnvm](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/blob/dev/GettingStartedDeb.md#get-dnvm) on an Ubuntu VM using Vagrant. In my vagrantfile I have a shell script that includes this line:
`curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.sh | DNX_BRANCH=dev sh && source /root/.dnx/dnvm/dnvm.sh`
which downloads and executes `dnvminstall.sh` which installs and puts `dnvm.sh` in /root/.dnx/dnvm. The `source /root/.dnx/dnvm/dnvm.sh` part doesn't seem to have worked because when I ssh into the machine I need to run it manually for dnvm to work.
So the question is, why isn't `source /root/.dnx/dnvm/dnvm.sh` executed during provisioning?
[Here](https://gist.github.com/chribben/dd0bb057a43f49dc1b5f)'s the vagrantfile in it's entirety.

Comment: Can we see the VagrantFile?

Comment: Yes added a link to it in the question

Comment: Ok. So I used to have a similar problem, and it wasn't that the script wasn't  executed, but it was being executed in a different session. I don't know what does your `dnvm.sh` script do, but what could be happening is that the whole thing is executed in the `provisioning` session, and then when you create a new session by `ssh`, it's like it never executed. It all depends on what it does. You can check that it is actually executed by putting some  printing to file function on `dnvm.sh`.

Comment: Very simple example. If you put `alias my_alias='ls'` in the script, it will execute it, but when you `ssh`, the alias won't be there, because it will have been created for another session: the `provisioning` one.

Comment: Ok, or maybe it is what @tobuslieven is answering :)

Comment: @tomasyany thanks, I'll try out your suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You're cding into `/usr/local/src/libuv-1.4.2` earlier in your script.

Then you're downloading dnvm into that directory using curl, then trying to run the file as if it was in `/root/.dnx/dnvm/dnvm.sh`, when it's actually somewhere under `/usr/local/src/libuv-1.4.2`

You just need to cd back into `/root` before you use curl to get dnvm. So ...

```
cd /root
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.sh | DNX_BRANCH=dev sh && source /root/.dnx/dnvm/dnvm.sh
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Good catch, however, the `dnvminstall.sh` script puts `dnvm.sh` in `/root/.dnx/dnvm/` regardless of where it is being executed from. I'll update the question to clarify.

Comment: `curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/dnvminstall.sh | DNX_BRANCH=dev sh && source /root/.dnx/dnvm/dnvm.sh` looks weird to me. So dnvminstall.sh is getting piped to sh. Then if that returns non zero, the second half of the && gets executed? So the source part only executes if the first part errors? (non zero is error in bash?) Perhaps I'm reading that wrong.

Comment: Ok I looked up the && in bash and I was reading it wrong. It's more like the following: So dnvminstall.sh is getting piped to sh. Then if that returns zero, the part after the && gets executed. So the source part only executes if the first part doesnt error. So I guess dnvminstall.sh is returning an error. Looking at the source, there seem to be a few opportunities for it to do that.

Comment: I don't think  `dnvminstall.sh` returns any error since when I ssh into the machine `dnvm.sh` is in fact installed under `/root/.dnx/dnvm`. It's just that it hasn't been executed. Or it partly failed but succeeded to put `dnvm.sh` there. I think I've tried to put `source /root/.dnx/dnvm/dnvm.sh` on a separate line but will try again.